# Rails RSpec testing a node class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to to write a test for a Node class which keeps failing,

here is my class:

```
class Node < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Node"
    has_many :children, :class_name => "Node", :foreign_key => "parent_id"

    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

and following are my failing tests

```
    it 'created successfully' do
        node = Node.new(name:"test1", parent_id:1).save
        expect(node).to be_truthy
    end

    it 'has root category' do
        expect(Node.where('parent_id = id').count).to eq(1) 
    end
```

the DB already has been seeded with the "root" node.

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Responses are as follows:

Example 1:

> ```
>    expected: truthy value
>         got: false
> ```

Example 2:

> ```
>    expected: 1
>         got: 0
> ```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: And I think, instead of `node = Node()`, `Node.new()` creates new instance

Comment: Also use `FactoryGirl` to create object of `Node`, instead of creating using `Node.new`

Comment: Rhunal,  sorry I forgot to add the new on the post, on my examples it already has it, I'll update the question with the RSpec responses as well.

Comment: It means your `Node` object is not saved, thats why you are getting these errors. Please advise, why you are not using `factory` to create object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Firstly try below in console:

```
node = Node.new(name:"test1", parent_id:1)
node.save!
node.errors.messages
```

Please provide this output. You can see here, what is the problem.

2.Use `factory` to create object of `Node`. Define the mandatory attributes to factory.

```
FactoryGirl.define :node do
  name 'John'
end
```

3.I think, you are missing here to create the object of `parent`, so that will be the reason not to save `node` object.

Define the mandatory attributes of `parent to factory.

```
FactoryGirl.define :parent do
  #put mandatory attributes here
end
```

4.Write spec as below :

```
describe 'Node' do

  let(:parent) { FactoryGirl.create(:parent) }

  let(:node) {
    FactoryGirl.build(
      :node,
      parent_id: parent.id
    )
  }

  before do
    node.save!
  end

  it 'should create node' do
    expect(node).to be_truthy
  end

  it 'should have root category' do
    expect(Node.where('parent_id = parent.id').count).to eq 1
  end

end
```

Comment: yep, you are correct the issue was the parent node was missing